# Fluidly stop a CSS3 Animation halted mid-animation?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm running into a small problem attempting to have an animation stopped mid-animation gracefully returning to the default state. I'm applying an animation to a child element using the `:hover` pseudoclass on a parent element, but would like the animation to gracefully return to the default state when I stop hovering on the element. I'm getting the feeling that I shouldn't be using the `:hover` pseudoclass here and there's another method of approaching it, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to transition off. It just instantly reverts to the base state, which of course makes sense because the animation is being stripped - but that's not the desired effect. This is the current HTML:

```
<div id="el1">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

and the current CSS

```
#el1 {
    margin-top: 100px;
    position: relative;
    background: transparent url(./image.png) no-repeat;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

#el1 .child {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0;
}

#el1:hover .child {
    -webkit-animation-name: semiopacity;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes semiopacity {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 0.4; }
}
```

To recap: There's a flashing white effect over the image when hovering. I want it to animate back to the original keyframe when I stop hovering instead of snapping back to "off". I can change either the HTML or CSS; no restrictions on how to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[css3 animation on :hover; force entire animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694323/css3-animation-on-hover-force-entire-animation)

Something similar asked a couple days ago. This person also wanted their entire animation to show after hover was removed. Check it out.

Comment: Well, at least we get the events `webkitAnimationEnd`, `mozAnimationEnd`, or `animationEnd` to make this easier. Thanks for the link, I searched for a bit but it's not straightforward how to phrase the problem, which made it hard to locate.