# CSS3 Animation + @keyframe run till the end

Tags: css, animation, hover, css-animations

I can't find the way to play an animation till the end when an element is :hover.

- When i :hover out, the animation reset - but i want it to continue till the end.
- [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5SueS/)

```
<div class="picture"></div>
```

```css
    .picture:hover {
       -webkit-animation:swing 1s ease-in-out;
    }


    @-webkit-keyframes swing {
      [...] 
    }
```

Comment: I guess the :hover tag is not enough to do this, i need js or others pseudo tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not a complete solution, but add the following to your picture class:

```
-webkit-animation:swing 3600ms ease-in-out 6000s;
-webkit-transform-origin:top;
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5SueS/4/

This solution no longer works in modern browsers.  Please see [css3 animation on :hover; force entire animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694323/css3-animation-on-hover-force-entire-animation)

Comment: Interesting, starting the animation after a while - but why does the animation don't stop on ':hover OUT', as the animation is tigger by ':hover'.

Comment: Because the same animation is being triggered on the picture class (albeit with a ridiculously long delay).  It sees that it too has the animation, so it continues to play even after the hover out.  There is probably a better way, like telling it to play the animation 0 times instead of the long delay as well, but it was the first thing I tried and it worked.

Comment: This solution doesn't work.

Comment: Correct, this solution no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

I did like this
http://jsfiddle.net/Z5aq7/

Instead of Hovering, I just made it a class (.animate) and adding the class on hover

```
$('.picture').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('animate');
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Seems that there is no pure css solutions, so best solution with JS:

[Stackoverflow - animation on hover force entire animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694323/css3-animation-on-hover-force-entire-animation)