# Rotate a div on mouse over and go on when mouse out

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have a div, which I rotate it 360 degrees with css transitions on hover style. When the mouse is out, animation stops and div returns to its original style. Is it possible to go on rotating until it complete 360 degree rotation even the mouse is out of the div ? I am looking for a pure css solution, not jscript.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: wheres your code? what have you tried? do you have a jsfiddle or codepen example

Comment: there's no js etc.  I'm making animation through css transitions

Comment: codepen and jsfiddle are just a place to put your code (html, js, and css) so we can see the issue in a editable environment to better help answer your question :)

Comment: have a look at this: http://dryicons.com/blog/2013/02/27/detecting-mouseenter-with-css-animations/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there isn't a neat solution for this. There is a workaround previously posted by [Robert McKee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765727/css3-animation-keyframe-run-till-the-end?answertab=active#tab-top) that consists in using an animation with a high delay in normal css selector.

There's the jsfiddle example with a rotation:
http://jsfiddle.net/akko82/FNKMF/

This line will do the job:

```
-webkit-animation:rotateAnimation 3600ms ease-in-out 6000s;
```

where rotateAnimation is our animation and the 6000s is the delay.