# Is it possible to queue CSS animations (example)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I currently use this JS animation plugin: http://www.2meter3.de/code/hoverFlow/ and the distinct result I like is the orange example. As far as I understand CSS transitions can only do the yellow example.

Is there a way to replicate this purely with CSS?

If not, then s there a way to use CSS transitions, but controlled by JS (jQuery) using the same principle (a good mix of both worlds)?

Maybe this could help my case: http://cortys.de/cssAnimate/

Comment: this might help you http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/hrnvadoz/

Comment: So you like when the elements animates all the way till the predefined end position even if the mouse has left? (The most desirable solution in most environments out in the wild is actually the behavior that does the yellow one (using `.stop()`)) which stops the animation if the element looses hover and from that position returns it to it's original position. Which is doable in CSS alone. Just saying.

Comment: The yellow is not very good, you can't "play" with the elements, it's boring imho. The orange - when done properly - reminds me of the flash menus and looks fancy if you scan across with the mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, that is not possible with CSS alone.

There is a trick to [make the animation run to the end on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765727/css3-animation-keyframe-run-till-the-end) by running another invisible animation on the element, but that doesn't work if you want to animate it back.

With a little bit of Javascript you can add a class to the element when the mouse hovers, then remove the class when the animation is complete:

```
$('div').mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).addClass('animate');
}).on('transitionend', function(){
  $(this).removeClass('animate');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/oq83suw3/

However, it seems that the transition end event isn't always triggered, so the elements can get stuck with the class added to them. You can use a timeout to remove the class instead:

```
$('div').mouseenter(function(){
  var e = $(this);
  e.addClass('animate');
  window.setTimeout(function(){
    e.removeClass('animate');
  }, 300);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/u3c2knfj/

Comment: Thanks, would this (changing class, using setTimeout) still yield a better performance than only animating with jQuery?

Comment: @Firsh: Yes, the CSS animation is implemented in the browser itself, while the jQuery animation is implemented in Javascript running in the browser. You should however also consider the browser support, e.g. that IE 8 doesn't support transitions.