# Finish CSS Animation After Leaving Hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a bar that flips vertically from blue to gray when hovered. When leaving hover, it goes back to blue. Great.

**PROBLEM**
It only does the animation for however long you are on its hover state. It does not finish the animation if you hover and "unhover" really quick.

**GOAL**
I want it to flip from blue to gray and back to blue even if hovered for a split second. I don't want the animation to immediately stop when you unhover.

**ATTEMPTS**
I've read that this can't be done with pure CSS.

I've tried adding the following jquery code that adds and removes an animation class from this question: [css3 animation on :hover; force entire animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694323/css3-animation-on-hover-force-entire-animation):

```
$(".bar").bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd", function(){
$(this).removeClass("vFlipper") 
})
$(".bar").hover(function(){
$(this).addClass("vFlipper");
})
```

And changing the CSS for `.vFlipper` to `.bar.vFlipper`, but I can't seem to get it working with my code. UL and LI's seem to always cause me issues. I understand how it works with DIVs, but not with lists.

**FIDDLE**
http://jsfiddle.net/zuhloobie/t9x723tq/1/

Any help would be appreciated :)

**## UPDATE ##**
I'm really close with this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zuhloobie/t9x723tq/8/

It's buggy though. When you enter the `li` from the left, it will flip to gray, but won't flip back to blue when you exit. When you enter the `li` from the top, right, or bottom...it doesn't flip to gray on hover, but it will do the whole animation when you exit. Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You should try this type of **code/syntax**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bar').bind( "click transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd", function() {
// css for doing flipping will go here;
//  alert( "User clicked on bar" );

});

$('#bar').bind( "click transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd", function() {
// css for returning/reversing flipper  will go here;
//  alert( "User clicked on bar" );

});

});
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. If I put both of those statements, though, won't it only read the last `('.bar')` since it is being repeated? It is also working off "click" and I need it to work off of hover like I posted. See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zuhloobie/t9x723tq/5/. It bypasses the first `('.bar')` because it is repeated - but it IS running its full animation though. Feels like it's close...

Comment: I've gotten it close with this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zuhloobie/t9x723tq/8/.
It's buggy though. Sometimes it doesn't flip to gray on first hover and  sometimes it does, but it doesn't flip back to blue when off hover. And the bug is random. Ideas?

Comment: What's even more weird. If you enter each `li` from the top, right, or bottom - it doesn't flip to gray on hover, but it will finish the animation. If you enter the `li` from the left, it will flip to gray on hover, but won't finish the animation. Losing my mind?

Comment: Are you unable to assist past your suggestion?

Comment: Sorry friend , I was out of town, as you say "Sometimes it doesn't flip to gray on first hover and sometimes it does, but it doesn't flip back to blue when off hover."  in this case you need to add embeded css for blue color (for off hover)