# Full hover animation duration with quick mouseover/mouseout?

Tags: html, css, hover, transition, state

I have a hovering effect on an image. If you mouseover it and stay there with the mouse, the transition will be execute with its given duration.

I have also done the correct transition when you leave the spot.

Now, i want that the hover transition starts with the given duration, no matter if you just hovered over the image for a quick 1millisecond.

Is this only possible with javascript?

```
.example { position: absolute;
             left: 0;
             height:320px;
             bottom: 0;
             width: 100%;
             background: #000;
             background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
             opacity:0;
             -webkit-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
             -moz-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
             -o-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
             -ms-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;

             transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
             -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
             -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
             -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
            -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
             transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
             text-align: center;
             line-height: 299px;
             text-decoration: none;
             color: #000000;
             font-size:30pt;
          }

   .image:hover .example { background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
                         -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s  ease-in-out;
                         -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s  ease-in-out;
                         -o-transition: background-color 0.5s  ease-in-out;
                         -ms-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
                         transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
                         -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s  ease-in-out;
                         -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s  ease-in-out;
                         -o-transition: opacity 0.5s  ease-in-out;
                         -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s  ease-in-out;
                         transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
                         opacity:1;
                       }
```

With this, if i hover over the image, my text and background colors animating in and when i leave the image the text and background color is animating out. It works okay. (even though, my above code is a bit unsorted for now)

So, all i want is that the fading in and out animation will be fully executed even if i just hover fast over the image and back.

I think it is not possible is it? (with css only i mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid, you would have to use a bit of Javascript because as far as I know, it is not possible to do it without javascript.

Add a class on hover, and remove it on animation end. Refer to this answer to know how to do that - [css3 animation on :hover; force entire animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694323/css3-animation-on-hover-force-entire-animation)

PS: I would have put this is a comment, but I don't have the privileges right now.

Comment: The OP is trying to figure out how to do this with mouseover (and presumably mouseout).  I modified the example from the link you posted to demonstrate how this can be done with these events:  http://jsfiddle.net/ue6mvm51/2/

Comment: Thanks @alex, should I add your fiddle to the answer as well for incase people want to try that it with that event ?

Comment: i will explain it again: If i mouseover, the background-color is fading in and stays if i dont mouseout. If i mouseout the bg-color is fading out. Thats the status quo of my code. Now, i want it like this: If i just do a mouseover  for a milisecond, the animation will only show 1 milisecond of itself. I want that it still fade in completely and fading out then. In the first example its pretty much the effect i want partially. If you move your mouse over all boxes from left to right. All animations are getting fully executed. Sorry for my english btw ;)

Comment: So, my basic question was if it is possible without javascript. I think i have to use js triggering mouseover and mouseout to fade the bg-color in and out.

Comment: I still don't understand the issue completely, could you create a fiddle and point us to that, so that we can give you a working solution.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wkcrdcf1/ Thats the status quo. My first question was, if it is possible to avoid the transition from stopping, if i hover fast over the image with css only. (So that the transition doesnt stop after 1 ms instead of 0.5s) It is possible with javascript, but i dont know how. Furthermore, i would have to trigger the element with js and not the whole class. (I have 25 images). In case you know some code ;)

Comment: It doesn't because i don't see a difference?

Comment: Thanks, but it is not fading back e.g.. I think we have to work with mouseover + mouseout since it should stay active if i stay on the pic and fade out if i leave. Plus my problem with starting the animation in AND out if i just hover fast over the image. =)

Comment: I guess we would have to use a combination of both, as we need it to fade out only when the mouse leaves and we need to it fade In completely even if the mouse leaves in between the fadeIn animation. 
Lemme know if you need help with that.

Comment: yes, exactly what it should do. Unfortunately i havent code js that much. So any help is appreciated

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3pb38v4f/7/ i did a quick update on this, cause it was stucked when u leave the mouse. I fixed it whit if (isTransition) instead of if (!isTransiotin)

Comment: Must have been some issue with the fiddle, because in my browser it fades out when you remove the mouse. 
The change you did will cause an issue, as it would end the transition as soon as you move your mouse out.

Comment: ow you are completely right. In chrome its working and well, it is exactly what i was looking for :) Thanks sir! Why is it not working with firefox? I will implement it quick,

Comment: Okay, there comes the problems. It works for several images, but then the transition is stucked (means, the text is visible all the time) I have to reload the page to make it dissapear. Furthermore it is only working with chrome for me. BUT: This is definitelly the right direction. Nice one!

Comment: I think we can close this answer now, and you should form a separate question for the problem you are facing now. The context of the problem has now changed from the initial one.

Comment: you are completely right. I will do so. Thanks mate.