# Transitioning from animated to not animated in Chrome vs Firefox

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions

Firefox has a nice behavior when turning off animation in a transition enabled element, it takes the element wherever it is and transition back to original form.

In Chrome it just jumps without transitioning.

Why the inconsistency? Is there any way to replicate in Chrome without using too much JS?

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}

.move {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f66;
  transition: 1s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.move {
  animation: move 2s linear infinite;
}

.wrapper:hover .move {
  animation: none;
}

@keyframes move {
  50% {
    transform: translateX(200px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="move"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".spinny").bind("webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd animationEnd", function(){
  $(this).removeClass("spin")  
})

$(".spinny").hover(function(){
  $(this).addClass("spin");        
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f66;
  transition: 1s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.spin {
  animation: spin 1s linear 1;
}

@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script><div class="spinny"></div>
```

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694323/css3-animation-on-hover-force-entire-animation), JS can be used to add and remove classes on hover and animation finish, respectively. jQuery is used in this example, but it is not necessary for the functionality.

**EDIT:** Now without jQuery, this will play the animation whenever hovered over by remembering the state and checking after the end of every animation.

```js
hover = 0;
s = document.getElementById("spinny");
s.addEventListener("animationend", function(){
  s.className = "";
  if (hover)
    setTimeout(function(){s.className = "spin"},0);
})

s.onmouseover = function(){
  s.className = "spin";
  hover = 1;
}

s.onmouseout = function(){
  hover = 0;
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f66;
  transition: 1s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.spin {
  animation: spin 1s linear 1;
}

@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="spinny"></div>
```

Comment: In my original use-case, I'm actually using JS to toggle the animated class, omitted in the question simply for brevity, yet it doesn't work anyway, I'm not sure how your example was supposed to answer my original question, given it simply doesn't work if I change it to 'infinite'

Comment: @Faccion In that case, you can keep the 1 second animation, and you can track the hover state to keep the animation running if it is still being hovered on after the 1 second.

Comment: I don't get it, can you modify the example to show what you mean?

Comment: Yes, I will. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add transition along side your transform

```css
.rotate {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: 0.5s ease all;
  background-color: #222;
  }
.rotate:hover {
  transform: rotate(20deg);
  transition: 0.5s ease all;
  }
```

This should prevent it from jumping.

Comment: I omitted prefixes in the question for brevity, but it doesn't work with them anyway