# CSS bounce hover animation jitters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a bounce animation occur on hover on my page (on an image of an arrow). However, if the cursor is near the top edge, it will generally jitter, due to the change of the position of the content area from what I can gather. The image will move, bringing your mouse out of the hover area, resetting the image position abruptly, and repeating until you move the mouse.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? Can be CSS/Javascript/some other library, doesn't matter to me.

```
.arrow-main {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 1%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 90px;
}

.bounce:hover {
    -webkit-animation:bounce .9s infinite;
    -moz-animation:bounce .9s infinite;
    -o-animation:bounce .9s infinite;
    animation:bounce .9s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0%       { bottom:10px; }
  50%      { bottom:0px; }
  100%     { bottom:10px; }
}

@-moz-keyframes bounce {
  0%       { bottom:10px; }
  50%      { bottom:0px; }
  100%     { bottom:10px; }
}

@-o-keyframes bounce {
  0%       { bottom:10px; }
  50%      { bottom:0px; }
  100%     { bottom:10px; }
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0%       { bottom:10px; }
  50%      { bottom:0px; }
  100%     { bottom:10px; }
}
```

I actually made a codepen to try and illustrate the issue, but it doesn't jitter at all... I'm using Chrome.

EDIT: Just tried the codepen again, and it jitters as it should.

EDIT 2: I modified the codepen to try out the comments so far, and if you hold your cursor near the bottom of the arrow img, you should get an idea of what I am trying to combat.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/corynorell/pen/LWXyVr)

Comment: maybe instead of `bottom: 1%;` just set it to 0. It should remove the start jitter, but not sure if you can do anything about the ending jitter

Comment: As @A.Lau said you can change the `bottom` value to remove the initial jitter. you can also remove the ending jitter using some javascript. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694323/css3-animation-on-hover-force-entire-animation) question.

Comment: I changed the codepen, and it's better. Perhaps what I'm seeing is both jitters if the mouse happens to move off the image? The arrow will basically rapidly dance about if you are near an edge... Maybe the codepen doesn't provide a good enough example. It is very prominent on my local test site.

Comment: I can probably make that Javascript solution work though, it seems I will only be able to do one bounce effectively that way however. Looks like that will be the most elegant option.