# CSS - Play animation while hovering, but not with an abrupt end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to create a sort of loading animation, with 3 bars that are below eachother that *all have seperate keyframes*.

The 3 bars are `div` elements, located inside a parent `div`.

```
<div id="menu">
    <div id="menubox1"></div>
    <div id="menubox2"></div>
    <div id="menubox3"></div>
</div>
```

The animation properties are assigned to the individual `menubox` ids.

```
#menubox1:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    border-top: 1px solid #FFDADA;

    animation: menukeyframes1;
    animation-duration: 2000ms;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-play-state: inherit;
}

@keyframes menukeyframes1 {
     0% { width: 100%; left:0;}
     ...
}
```

My goal is to play the animation **while the cursor is hovering over the parent div**.

My attempt was to play around with `animation-play-state` which was set to `running` or `paused`, depending if the parent `div` was hovered.

The problem is that the animation is *immediatly* paused, before the animation is complete, which looks kind of bad if it stops mid-motion.

Is there a good fix for this, preferrably without JavaScript/jQuery, and across all browsers?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm assuming this is the abrupt ending you don't want? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/vZBXgY Sounds like you want to trigger `paused` using the `animationend` event in the browser, which requires js.

Comment: @MichaelCoker This is exactly what I currently have. What would be the easiest and cleanest way to achieve my goal with js though?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sSYYE/55/. This is a slightly updated version from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694323/css3-animation-on-hover-force-entire-animation#comment-56413462.

Comment: @WizardCoder Thats looking good! Does it require me switching my bars from ids to classes or is there another way?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sSYYE/56/ I have updated the fiddle to make it more relevant to your code.

Comment: @WizardCoder Apparently I am doing something wrong ... i have posted my attempt, based on your answer, on this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L22u0dgk/2/

Comment: It was just CSS related issue. You needed to apply `:after` to the `.anim` selectors. e.g. `#menubox1.anim1:after`. https://jsfiddle.net/L22u0dgk/3/. The rest of it is up to you to adjust the styling. There is a lot of repeated styles that could be cleaned up.

Answer (score 1):

As you see it can't be done with just CSS at this moment, and as good jquery answers are already referenced, it's worth to mention that it could be solved in few lines of vanillaJS:

```
var dur = 2000;
document.querySelectorAll('.smooth').forEach(el=>{
  var t;
  el.addEventListener('mouseover',_=>{t = performance.now();el.style.animationPlayState = 'running'})
  el.addEventListener('mouseout',_=>window.setTimeout(()=>el.style.animationPlayState = 'paused',dur-(performance.now()-t)%dur));
})
```

[working pen](https://codepen.io/mackie_pl/pen/bRbwRq)

non-es6: [BABEL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code=var%20dur%20%3D%202000%3B%0D%0Adocument.querySelectorAll('.smooth').forEach(el%3D%3E%7B%0D%0A%20%20var%20t%3B%0D%0A%20%20el.addEventListener('mouseover'%2C_%3D%3E%7Bt%20%3D%20performance.now()%3Bel.style.animationPlayState%20%3D%20'running'%7D)%0D%0A%20%20el.addEventListener('mouseout'%2C_%3D%3Ewindow.setTimeout(()%3D%3Eel.style.animationPlayState%20%3D%20'paused'%2Cdur-(performance.now()-t)%25dur))%3B%0D%0A%7D))

Comment: Is there anything special about your code? It throws me some errors, such as `esversion 6 is needed for => arrow` or `_ is not defined`.

Comment: It's es6, if you can't use it it's easy to transpile, even online: [BABEL](https://babeljs.io/repl/)

Comment: Plus 1 for using vanilla js. Very fancy.

Answer (score 0):

You can always fade out the animated divs using transitions.
Something like this might work for you:

```
#menubox1 {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s linear;
}

#menu:hover {
  #menubox1 {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .5s linear;
  }
}
```