# Keeping the transition even when the hover state is gone

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I have a div container and when i hover on this container, i'm displaying another div on top my container by changing the opacity of the second div from 0 to 1. When i click on the second div (which appeared when hovering my container), i'm doing an animation. The problem i'm facing is, when the animation starts and at that same time if i move the mouse pointer away from my container, the animation also disappears without completing the animation. How can i keep the animation till it completes if i move the mouse pointer away from the container after clicking on it.

My container

```
<div key={index} className='vote_img_div active_imgvote_border'>


    <div className="vote_img unchange_div">

            //contents

    </div>


    <div onClick={() => this.handleClick(content.post_poll_content_id)}
         className={((this.state.voted_id === content.post_poll_content_id && this.state.active) ? 'vote_card_hover active' : 'vote_card_hover')}>


    </div>

</div>
```

My css

```
.vote_img_div {

    width: 292.5px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 8.25px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;

}

.vote_img {

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;

}

.vote_card_hover {

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .3s ease;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .70);

}

.vote_card_hover:before {

    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: rgba(0, 111, 147, 0.70);
    transition: transform 0.8s ease;
    border-radius: 50%;

}

.vote_card_hover.active:before {

    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);

}

.vote_img_div:hover .vote_card_hover {
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);


}

.active {
    background: rgba(103, 173, 237, 0.7);
    color: #FFFFFF;

}
```

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694323/css3-animation-on-hover-force-entire-animation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css3 animation on :hover; force entire animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694323/css3-animation-on-hover-force-entire-animation)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `animation-fill-mode` to `forwards`, if you want keep animation state.

You can also use shorthand like there - https://github.com/cmachu/ewok/

Answer (score 0):

This is how regular hover is supposed to act. If you want the element to change permanently, remove the `.vote_img_div:hover` from your css and just redefine your element class using onclick event, which you're already doing. The transition attribute makes sure it moves, but when the mouse leaves the animation will be finished nevertheless and new class maintained.