# Add animation after hovering over a div with CSS transform scale

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

```css
@keyframes hvr-pulse-grow {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}

.hvr-pulse-grow {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
}

.hvr-pulse-grow:hover,
.hvr-pulse-grow:focus,
.hvr-pulse-grow:active {
  -webkit-animation-name: hvr-pulse-grow;
  animation-name: hvr-pulse-grow;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.9s;
  animation-duration: 0.9s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    ALBERT
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tes.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="hvr-pulse-grow"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

This works well but can I add a `transition` to go to the initial state more slowly after I move the mouse out of the box? Does anyone know a solution for this? The animation needs to be repeated infinitely as far as the user hovering over the div.

Comment: what is the purpose of repeating the question :) if you didn't get a good reply, simply  edit it with more information ... no need to delete and re-post

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694323/css3-animation-on-hover-force-entire-animation).

Comment: could you please provide some feedback regarding my edit, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can slow down the "mouseleave" event by adding an animation to the normal state of the element as well as a `from` key to the `:hover` animation.

This resolves your issue in pure `CSS`, but it would be much simpler and cleaner to handle this animation with `jQuery` or `javascript`. With `jQuery`, you could simply add a `transition` for all properties in your `CSS`, then handle animating both the mouseenter and mouseleave events with [`hover()` method](https://api.jquery.com/hover/).

Hope this helps!

```css
.hvr-pulse-grow {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
  -webkit-animation-name: hvr-pulse-grow-out;
  animation-name: hvr-pulse-grow-out;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.9s;
  animation-duration: 0.9s;
}

.hvr-pulse-grow:hover {
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-animation-name: hvr-pulse-grow-in;
  animation-name: hvr-pulse-grow-in;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.9s;
  animation-duration: 0.9s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes hvr-pulse-grow-in {
    from   { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
    to { -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);}
}

@keyframes hvr-pulse-grow-out {
    from   { -webkit-transform: scale(1.1); }
    to { -webkit-transform: scale(1);}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    ALBERT
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tes.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="hvr-pulse-grow"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is what you are aiming for.

notice the added `transition` to the square when it is not *focused*, *hovered* nor *active*, this way it will still *transition* (instead of snap back) to its original state when it is no longer being hovered.

NOTE: According to [Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif), this does not work and since it is so simple (one line) I don't know what to do but wait for a third opinion (hopefully the OP's) before trying to find and fix the glitch.

Let me know how it fares

```css
@keyframes hvr-pulse-grow {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    transform: scale(2);        
  }
}
.hvr-pulse-grow {
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background:red;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
  transition: 0.9s ease all
}
.hvr-pulse-grow:hover, .hvr-pulse-grow:focus, .hvr-pulse-grow:active {
  -webkit-animation-name: hvr-pulse-grow;
  animation-name: hvr-pulse-grow;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.9s;
  animation-duration: 0.9s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        ALBERT 
    </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tes.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="hvr-pulse-grow"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why adding a transition ? it will do absolutely nothing ... what the difference between your code and his code ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif; oh man, did you really down vote? did you even bother running my snippet against the OP's? he wanted a smooth exit on hover out, no? he got it, please provide some useful feedback

Comment: you really see a smooth exit on your code ? :) if yes then am blind ... and don't worry, i run snippet and check the code before commenting or downvoting

Comment: well, I'm in FF and TBH I did not check other browsers, maybe that's it? because I AM seeing a smooth hover out

Comment: i also test with FF and am not sure what are you seeing ...before even testing, tell me what is the logic of adding a transition ? to do transition between what ? on hover you run an animation and you are not changing a property so transition has no effect here

Comment: try to make the scale value bigger, am sure you are having a glitch

Comment: @TemaniAfif; this is weird, just to rule this out: are you saying you are seeing the exact same behaviour in the OP's snippet (where the square snaps back to original size on hover out) than in mine? because I just set the scale to 5 and I AM seeing a smooth exit, as smooth as I don't know... look, there is really not much I can do, it's not like I don't want to yield, I WOULD LOVE FINDING OUT THAT GLITCH YOU ARE SEEING, but I just see it work perfectly, which makes me really concerned about my browser's health, ;)

Comment: can you create a gif, or a small video ? maybe we are not talking about the same effect ? .. and yes your code is exactly the same as the OP code for me

Comment: @TemaniAfif; maybe this won't help but what do you see here: https://jsfiddle.net/rem5y0wu/ (don't know how to make a `.gif`, tell no one :(

Comment: i tested your code with Chrome, Firefox and IE ... i see the same behavior and no smooth exit ... also there is no logic to have a smooth exit with your code ... if you are convinced then add explanation about how it works