# Bounce keyframe animation on hover out stops abruptly

Tags: html, css

As you can see in the below animation, if you hover out then the animation stops abruptly. I would like to transition it to the final position down. Is there a way to do it while keeping keyframes?

```css
.bounce{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    margin-top:100px;
}

.bounce:hover {
    animation-name: bounce;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0%, 100%, 20%, 50%, 80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform:     translateY(0);
    transform:         translateY(0)
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
    -ms-transform:     translateY(-30px);
    transform:         translateY(-30px)
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
    -ms-transform:     translateY(-15px);
    transform:         translateY(-15px)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bounce"></div>
```

Comment: unfortunately, no with pure CSS

Comment: not in css dude. you have to use js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css3 animation on :hover; force entire animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694323/css3-animation-on-hover-force-entire-animation)

Comment: @TemaniAfif how would you do it with jquery? simple class add and remove doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Gerard thanks but that one uses jquery bind which has been deprecated so no useful answers