# How to make the animation continue even if not hovering

Tags: html, css

When i'm hovering an img, i want it to rotate. My problem is when i hover the img it rotates but if i stop hovering it, it just goes to how it was initially, it doesn't continue the animation... I want the img to rotate when hovering it and continue even if i mouve the mouse out of the img. Also no JS please, I only want to use CSS

ps: Sorry for my bad english, I'm french :P

```
    0% {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

img:hover{
    animation-name: Animation;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [css3 animation on :hover; force entire animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694323/css3-animation-on-hover-force-entire-animation)

Comment: I only want to use css, no JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```css
@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
img:hover{
    -moz-animation: rotation .6s infinite linear;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    -o-animation: rotation .6s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: rotation .6s infinite linear;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    animation: rotation .6s infinite linear;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/1ebceb30742d4815e63f649cbb853834?s=32&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG&amp;f=1">
```

Comment: Where is the hover part?