# finish animation when stop hovering

Tags: css, css-animations

I was trying to animate an icon in a button when you are hovering with this code:

```
.mail:hover i {
  animation: correo 1s;
}

@keyframes correo {
  20% {
    transform: translate(-10px);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(100px);
  }
  81% {
    transform: translate(0, -50px);
  }
}
```

The problem is that when you stop hovering in the middle of the animation, it returns to the original positon, but not smoothly. So what I was wondering is if theres some way to finish the animation when you stop hovering.

I tryied it with transitions since return to the original position smoothly but i can't add two `transform: translate();` in one transition

here you have the code: https://jsfiddle.net/ch0x267q/1/

Comment: no need to delete and repeat the same question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/65641866/8620333)

Comment: is not the same question as the one you gave me.

Comment: ok finallly solved, the question was a different one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56740695/14861539