# CSS, how to keep playing animation when unhovered?

Tags: html, css

I want play the whole animation when mouse is hovered.
(not to stop when unhovered)

How can I make it?

```
.textBox {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
}

.textBox__Item:hover {
  animation: rubberFonts 1.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="textBox">
  <span class="textBox__Item">A</span>
  <span class="textBox__Item">B</span>
  <span class="textBox__Item">C</span>
  <span class="textBox__Item">D</span>
  <span class="textBox__Item">E</span>
  <span class="textBox__Item">F</span>
  <span class="textBox__Item">G</span>
  <span class="textBox__Item">H</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694323/css3-animation-on-hover-force-entire-animation answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s how I would do it (possibly not the best way)

Make a JavaScript function that adds a class to the element when the `onmouseover` event occurs.

Your JavaScript function should go as follows (example for one span):

```
function applyclassrubber(){
    Span1.classList.add("rubberfont");
}
```

Your CSS should be like this:

```
.rubberfont {
    animation: rubberFonts 1.5s;
}
```

And your HTML (example for one span as you would need to do this for all of them.) should go like this:

```
<span id="Span1" class="textBox__Item" onmouseover="applyclassrubber">A</span>
```

I forgot to mention this earlier but you will have to set a `timeout` when the `onmouseover` event occurs which removes the class after 15 seconds. (Just tell me if you want me to tell you how).